# mouseout event handler isn't trrigering

Tags: easeljs

I have a strange behavior in my app:
I have a collection of shapes that each one of them has a mouseover and mouseout event handlers.
When the user moves over a shape, its color changes and then when he moves out of it, its color returns to the original color.

The thing that I don't understand is sometimes, the mouseout event isn't trigering at all and the color of the shape remains with the hovered state.

I try to print to the console and couldn't find a problem. All I know is that it doesn't enters the mouseouse handler

```
var onMouseOver = function (e, sha, container) {
if (seat.isHovered) return;
$('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    var curHoveredShape = sha;
    var newShape = new createjs.Shape();
    newShape .addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
        onShapeMouseOut(e, e.target, e.target.parent);
    });
    newShape .graphics.beginFill(hoverdSeatColor).drawRoundRect(0, 0, 5, 5, 1.5);
    newShape .x = curHoveredSeat.x;
    newShape .y = curHoveredSeat.y;
    newShape .parent = container;
    sha.removeEventListener("mouseover", arguments.callee);
    container.removeChild(sha);
    container.addChild(newShape );
    newShape .isHovered = true;      
    lastHoveredSeat = newShape ;

    stage.update();      
}
```

Here's the code for the mouseout:

```
var onMouseOut = function (e) { 
    var curShape= e.target; 
    var container = e.target.parent;

    $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    var newShape = new createjs.Shape();
    newShape.graphics.beginFill(selectedSeatColor).drawRoundRect(0, 0, 5, 5, 1.5);
    newShape.x = curShape.x;
    newShape.y = curShape.y;
    newShape.parent = container;
    curShape.removeEventListener("mouseout", arguments.callee);
    container.removeChild(curShape);
    container.addChild(newShape);
    newShape.isHovered = false;
    lastHoveredSeat = null;
    newShape.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        onSeatMouseOver(e, e.target, e.target.parent);
    });
    stage.update();
    $(mapManagerObj).trigger("onSeatHoveredOut");        
}
```

Comment: Ok. No comment so far.
I created a fiddle - maybe this will help to shed some light.
As you can see, sometimes, the onover color appears abut when the cursor is our, the mouse out isn't triggering.
http://jsfiddle.net/aK5Cz/

Comment: I noticed that it happens when I'm moving relatively fast over the shape - if that helps anyone